# Visualforce Charting limitation

Tags: visualforce-charting

I am reading on [Visualforce Charting Limitations and Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_limitations.htm), and notice this sentences :

- Dynamic (Apex-generated) charting components are not supported at
  this time.

I want to know the scope under this limitation.I think it support dynamic data but not automatic chart generation.In [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) , I can generate 0-N charts based on query.Example if the Account has three segments, the three chart will automatically generated.This is cannot be done in Visualforce charting(correct me if I am wrong).

What else that related to apex-generated features that not supported under Visualforce charting?

----------------------------------------- Update------------------------------------------

How about plotting?For exampple in [radar chart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_appearance_radar_charts.htm?search_text=RADAR) , it use :

```
<apex:radarSeries xField="name" yField="data1" tips="true" opacity="0.4"/>
    <apex:radarSeries xField="name" yField="data2" tips="true" opacity="0.4"/>
    <apex:radarSeries xField="name" yField="data3" tips="true" 
        markerType="cross" strokeWidth="2" strokeColor="#f33" opacity="0.4"/>
```

Can we generate apex:radarSeries dynamically based on how many data[N] ?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic charts here implies using dynamic Visualforce components where you generate a markup using the apex .A good example of a dynamic component is this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dynamicComponent.htm) where you use apex like **Component.Apex.Detail**

The limitations does not imply to the Highcharts .You can use Highchart library and use Javascript remoting to feed requsite data and should work .

Comment: @msrivastav13 I updated my question because it messy when I put here.How about plotting (refer to question)